# how to get the path of a specific page

Tags: servlets

My web project is structured as follows:

```
MyProject
   |--src
      |--buisness
         |--Mypage.jsp
         |--Myservlet.java
   |--index.jsp
```

In my index page I have a form which contains two buttons "OK" and $NO" and and sends the content of some fields to myServlet.  I would, in my servlet, redirect the result to Mypage.jsp in the case where the button "NO" is clicked. The problem I don't know to get the url of Mypage.jsp

Any help please ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough detail to answer this question with certainty but the most likely answer is your can't. Mypage.jsp appears to have been placed with the source code rather than with the static files. Move it alongside index.jsp and then it should be accessible.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your help. Mypage.jsp is one of several pages for which I want to access out of my static files directory and I don't want to put all of them there. Is there a way to access any page within another (here Myservlet) by code.